# Accessing field of a nested class in Java

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a class that contains 3 nested classes within it. I am looking for a way to access a field of one
of the nested classes.

```
public class NestedClasses {

  class Outer {
    class InnerOne {
      int item1;
      int item2;
    }
    class InnerTwo {
      int item1;
      int item2;
    }
  }

//get access to item1 inside InnerOne
```

How can I access item1 inside InnerOne to assing a value to it?

I tried:

```
Outer.InnerOne test = new Outer.InnerOne();
x.item1 = 5;
```

but the first line is not valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nesting a class within a class is usually for the outer class to use the inner class internally. If you need to create instances of `InnerOne` *outside* of `Outer`, then it should be nested in `Outer`. What you're doing is a major violation of the Law of Demeter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate each class

```
NestedClasses nested = new NestedClasses();
Outer outer = nested.new Outer();
Outer.InnerOne inner = outer.new InnerOne();
inner.item1 = 5;
```